# Nested SplitviewControllers

Tags: ios, nested, uisplitviewcontroller

I need nested split view controllers for my app. I need to present a split view controller in detail view of MGSplitViewController. How to do that? Pls help me. I need two separate master views.

I have attached the design here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of open source libraries that can help you implement that view structure. 
Check out : https://github.com/steipete/PSStackedView

Comment: Thanks but it is not two uisplitviewcontrollers.I need to do that with split view controllers